# How to secure HDFS on DC/OS without Enterprise

Tags: authentication, hdfs, dcos

I'm trying to secure HDFS cluster on open source DC/OS but it seems it's not an easy thing.
The problem I see in HDFS is the fact that it uses username of current system user so without any form of authentication anyone can just create user with certain username and get superuser permissions on cluster.

So I need any form of authentication. IP auth would be fine(clients with certain IPs can only connect to HDFS) but I couldn't find if there's an option to enable it.

Creating Kerberos for HDFS is not an option because running another service just to run another service to run another service etc. will only give tons of work.

If enabling any form of viable security is impossible, is there any other DC/OS HDFS-like service I  can use? I need some HA storage to fetch config files and sometimes jars from Artifact Uris to run services. I also need a place to store parquet files from spark streaming.

Version of DC/OS HDFS is 2.6.x.

Comment: _"anyone can just create user with certain username and get superuser permissions on cluster"_ > no need for root privs, just `export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs`  before using the Java API...

Comment: For a good overview about Hadoop security (not only authentication) read the slides from https://berlinbuzzwords.de/17/session/building-fence-around-your-hadoop-environments

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Sorry but I said Kerberos will make the infrastructure too complicated for out little needs. Also, you won't help anyone by being rude. If my post is too complicated for you then I will ask simple thing: Can HDFS be secured without using other services? If not, is there good alternative to HDFS in DC/OS that can do it? We need securing HDFS just for one simple usecase, we don't need anything else from it and it's already claiming huge amount of resources and we don't want to allocate even more for it. Anyway, I've already found the answers to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that Kerberos is the only real form of authentication in HDFS. Without this, HDFS will trust every user.